# Picking HARDWARE for building a web server with norco 1204 1u case

Tags: web, hardware

I'm running few tube sites and i'm planning a new server for the next 3 years. 
I already have norco 1204 case, with supermicro 600w psu.

The plan is to use:
1. 4X3TB SATA HD's in RAID6 for video streaming. 
2. 2x120GB SSD in RAID1 for system, sql and php files.

(Some may think that it will not fit, but it does)

I want to use a motherboard with 2 cpu's, as much ram as possible and a raid card that supports ssd, but i don't know which hardware to pick.

My budget for the motherboard, 2 cpu's and raid card is about **1900$.** 
Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Avi.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick update, Half a year ago I finished to build the server, here is the final spec:

Case:

NORCO RPC-1204
PSU:

SuperMicro PWS-563-1H 600w

#### The psu does not fit with screws

Motherboard:

Supermicro MBD-X9DRL-IF-B

2X Xeon E5 2609 with Dynatron R18 1u cooling

DDR3 ECC:

4XHynix DDR3 1333mhz PC3L-10600R

Raid:

LSI 3Ware 9750-8i + LSIiBBU07 batery

2 SFF-8087 raid cables

HD's:

4 SSD INTEL 330 120GB (raid 10) - OS, SQL, PHP FILES

4 Hitachi 4TB (Raid 5) - VIDEO FILES

And,

A picture of the server build:

http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7788/serverx.jpg